# jquery addClass misbehaving on 1 occasion, working on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass

Probably this question might get closed as too broad but I had to post as it is troubling me since some time now with no success with searching on the net.

I have a code which adds a class to an existing element on some event using jquery's `addClass` method. This is working fine is most of my pages of my website except 1. I am not able to find what it is that is creating the problem.

In this particular page, the addClass is replacing the current value in the class attribute to `undefined`.

The following is the javascript code

```
$(this).find('.searchbox').addClass('wid344');
```

The following is my element which the above code adds class to

```
<input id="SearchBx" type="text" class="searchbox" name="search_text" value="">
```

The following is what it gets converted into

```
<input id="SearchBx" type="text" class="undefined" name="search_text" value="">
```

In rest of the pages it is getting converted into

```
<input id="SearchBx" type="text" class="searchbox wid344" name="search_text" value="">
```

1 difference I found was that in the pages which are working the jquery version is 1.4.2 and the one which is not working is 1.6.4 but I am not able to find anything related to addClass between them.

Can anyone please let me know what could I be missing?

Please let me know if you need any further information at all.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
The page which is breaking is here (link removed for security reasons). There is a magnifying glass at the end which should show/hide a textbox which is not working. This is working fine in other pages.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle with the appropriate jQuery version? And what's `$(this)` in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. In the `ic_commons.js` file you are overriding the `String.prototype.trim` function that jQuery uses, and it has a mistake.

You have it defined like:

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return
    (this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, ""));
};
```

And you have to remove the break-line:

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return (this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, ""));
};
```

It was always returning nothing!

*--- Previous answer that take me to the error---*

Well, I have found that the problem is in the `trim` function used inside the AddClass of jQuery. In 1.4.2 it uses an implemented function done by jQuery, but in 1.6.4 it tries to use the Javascript `String.prototype.trim` function, and for some reason I don't know it is returning undefined.

You could add this after you add jQuery in your code to change the trim function to the one used in 1.4.2 without chaning the whole jQuery (but I don't know if it will break something):

```
$.trim = function( text ) {
    return (text || "").replace( "/^(\s|\u00A0)+|(\s|\u00A0)+$/g", "" );
}
```

You can try it opening the javascript console before hovering the element, execute that code and you will see it works.

Comment: @samar I have updated my previous answer with the actual error. I will not erase the previous (I will just put it below) because it explain how I found that the error was on the trim function.

Comment: This seems to work. What I have done is added your latest code i.e. `$.trim=...` as the first line in `$('#searchwrapper').mouseenter(function () {`. This is also not breaking the other pages. Please let me know if this is the correct way to go about it. BTW +1 from my end. Will mark it as answer once I thoroughly check it. Thanks a million. :)

Comment: @samar check my edited answer, I actually found that the problem was in another part of the code. If you change that then you don't have to override the $.trim function. :)

Comment: Yes I added the code given in your edited portion only. Just wanted to confirm if I have added in the right place. Please refer my previous comment and let me know.

Comment: @samar Sorry for the late respond. If you can you should edit that code directly inside the `ic_commons.js`, not adding it again, because that function is not correctly formed. After edit it in that file, it should work in all pages in the way it should work, because now it is overwriting the Javscript `trim` function with a function that does not work correctly. I hope I have explained it correctly. If you can't edit that file, add that code just after the `ic_commons.js` file is added, so it always works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

if add class dont works for you you can do it as following using attr() function.

eg.

$('#SearchBx').attr('class',$('#SearchBx').attr('class')+ ' wid344' );

not sure where the undefinded come from
hope may help you.

Comment: it seems to be working but when the mouse leaves it is breaking. I guess I would have to change the mouseleave as well to match your code. Will give it a shot and let you know.

Answer (score -2):

you can also:

```
$('#SearchBx').removeClass('wid344').addClass('wid344');
```

I removed it first, cause it could be that the class was already in it.

Comment: if the class before was showing result X and when DOM changed it should show result Y, it will not refresh to the new state.

Comment: Err... I really don't follow you there